# nativescript - webpack error

Tags: webpack, nativescript

Trying to integrate webpack into my Android app.

Followed instructions on [NS Webpack](https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/bundling-with-webpack).

1. When I try to build the app - I get an error app.css not found. I don't have one because I'm using scss. Why is webpack looking for app.css.

I put in a dummy file and got past that error - and build ok.

2. When I try to run it, I get:

```html
Preparing project...
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Executing after-prepare hook from C:\Users\MyPC\nativescript\test4b\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-dev-sass.js
All SASS source files removed from app package
Skipping package build. No changes detected on the native side. This will be fast!
Installing...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
Starting...
Successfully started on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
JS: Subscription constr ***
JS: APP LAUNCHED Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=dev.crewapps.test/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity }
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.crewapps.test/com.tns.NativeScriptAct
ivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/cal-page.xml:31:9
System.err:  > Module '/data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer' not found for element
'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer:RadSideDrawer'.
System.err:    > com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "/data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/nativescr
ipt-telerik-ui/sidedrawer", relative to: app//
System.err:       com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1084)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:966)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:953)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:937)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:929)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:13)
System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js, line: 9461, column: 20
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ScopeError', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 8202
, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'SourceError', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 821
3, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 9480, column:
17
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 9461, column:
33
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 25470, column:
 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.EasySAXParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/ap
p/vendor.js', line: 26338, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.XmlParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/ve
ndor.js', line: 25517, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.XmlStringParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/
app/vendor.js', line: 9467, column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'parseInternal', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 9
312, column: 11
System.err:     Frame: function:'loadPage', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 9396,
column: 27
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11473, column:
 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11492, column:
 20
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.FrameBase.navigate', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.test/files/app
/vendor.js', line: 11548, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/dev.c
rewapps.test/files/app/vendor.js', line: 2829, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'module.exports.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/dev.crewapps.tes
t/files/app/vendor.js', line: 31337, column: 25
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/cal-page.xml:31:9
```

This app worked fine without webpack - so I know the xml and plugin setup is correct.

The sidedrawer plugin is present.

Any help?

webpack.config.js

```html
const { resolve, join  } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");


const mainSheet = `app.css`;

module.exports = env => {
    const platform = getPlatform(env);

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const path = resolve(nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform));

    const entry = {
        // Discover entry module from package.json
        bundle: `./${nsWebpack.getEntryModule()}`,

        // Vendor entry with third-party libraries
        vendor: `./vendor`,

        // Entry for stylesheet with global application styles
        [mainSheet]: `./${mainSheet}`,
    };

    const rules = getRules();
    const plugins = getPlugins(platform, env);
    const extensions = getExtensions(platform);

    const config = {
        context: resolve("./app"),
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry,
        output: {
            pathinfo: true,
            path,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions,

            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],

            alias: {
                '~': resolve("./app")
            },
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
        },
        module: { rules },
        plugins,
    };

    if (env.snapshot) {
        plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            projectRoot: __dirname,
            webpackConfig: config,
            targetArchs: ["arm", "arm64", "ia32"],
            tnsJavaClassesOptions: { packages: ["tns-core-modules" ] },
            useLibs: false
        }));
    }

    return config;
};


function getPlatform(env) {
    return env.android ? "android" :
        env.ios ? "ios" :
        () => { throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!") };
}

function getRules() {
    return [
        {
            test: /\.html$|\.xml$/,
            use: [
                "raw-loader",
            ]
        },
        // Root stylesheet gets extracted with bundled dependencies
        {
            test: new RegExp(mainSheet),
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
                {
                    loader: "resolve-url-loader",
                    options: { silent: true },
                },
                {
                    loader: "nativescript-css-loader",
                    options: { minimize: false }
                },
                "nativescript-dev-webpack/platform-css-loader",
            ]),
        },
        // Other CSS files get bundled using the raw loader
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: new RegExp(mainSheet),
            use: [
                "raw-loader",
            ]
        },
        // SASS support
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "raw-loader",
                "resolve-url-loader",
                "sass-loader",
            ]
        },


        // Compile TypeScript files, replace templateUrl and styleUrls.
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                "awesome-typescript-loader",
            ]
        }

    ];
}

function getPlugins(platform, env) {
    let plugins = [
        new ExtractTextPlugin(mainSheet),

        // Vendor libs go to the vendor.js chunk
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ["vendor"],
        }),

        // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
        }),

        // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: mainSheet },
            { from: "css/**" },
            { from: "fonts/**" },
            { from: "**/*.jpg" },
            { from: "**/*.png" },
            { from: "**/*.xml" },
        ], { ignore: ["App_Resources/**"] }),

        // Generate a bundle starter script and activate it in package.json
        new nsWebpack.GenerateBundleStarterPlugin([
            "./vendor",
            "./bundle",
        ]),
        
        // Support for web workers since v3.2
        new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),

        // Generate report files for bundles content
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: join(__dirname, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: join(__dirname, "report", `stats.json`),
        }),
    ];

    if (env.uglify) {
        plugins.push(new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true }));

        // Work around an Android issue by setting compress = false
        const compress = platform !== "android";
        plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle: { except: nsWebpack.uglifyMangleExcludes },
            compress,
        }));
    }

    return plugins;
}

// Resolve platform-specific modules like module.android.js
function getExtensions(platform) {
    return Object.freeze([
        `.${platform}.ts`,
        `.${platform}.js`,
        ".ts",
        ".js",
        ".css",
        `.${platform}.css`,
    ]);
}
```

I see there's a mainSheet definition for the app.css - can I comment that out?

ns 3.2
nativescript-dev-webpack 0.8.0

Comment: Can you please post your `webpack.config.js` file and associated NPM versions for `nativescript-dev-webpack`?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for the bundle-config called out in the instructions you linked to? An example can be found here: https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/master/app/bundle-config.ts. After, you need to require/import the bundle-config in your app.ts file: https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/bundling-with-webpack.

Comment: In my bundle-config.ts file - I did do it for coupla of my modules - but not for every module I'm using. Do I have to do it for every module?

Comment: It looks like any UI related module needs to be registered. i.e. The side-drawer module that it is complaining about.

Comment: Similar issue has been resolved here (with the solution provided by Sean) https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/webpack-module-nativescript-telerik-ui-sidedrawer-not-found-for-element-nativescript-telerik-ui-sidedrawer-radsidedrawer/909